# DataView.Sort is a performance bottleneck

Tags: c#, performance, dataview

I have a performance bottleneck on a DataView.Sort. The code is below.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Filters the data table and returns a new data table with only the filtered rows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dtInput">The dt input.</param>
    /// <param name="filterExpression">The filter expression.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual DataTable FilterDataTable(DataTable dtInput, string filterExpression)
    {
        DataTable result = dtInput;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterExpression) && filterExpression.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            DataView view = new DataView(dtInput);
            view.RowFilter = filterExpression;
            view.Sort = HierarchyFieldMap.DisplayedValue;
            result = view.ToTable();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any idea's on how to improve this method?

It takes ~1 second to execute.

**EDIT**

I found this link on [DataView's Poor Peformance with Large RecordSets](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022183741/http://geekswithblogs.net/chrisfalter/archive/2006/08/15/88057.aspx)

Comment: It depends. 50 to 100k is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not returning a `DataView` but a `DataTable`, you should be able to get a performance boost - not order-of-magnitude, but 25-30% - by using `DataTable.Sort`:

```
private static DataTable SortDataTable(DataTable t, 
   string filterExpression,
   string sortExpression)
{
    DataTable t1 = t.Clone();
    t1.BeginLoadData();
    foreach (DataRow r in t.Select(filterExpression, sortExpression))
    {
        t1.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
    }
    t1.EndLoadData();

    return t1;
}
```

Most of the time that's being taken up there is copying the data into the new table.  If you can avoid creating a new table and work with the array of `DataRow`s that `DataTable.Select` returns you can get a considerable improvement.

Comment: There is no reason to create a new table. I was turned off by the Select because it a DataRow[] is returned. I figured it put me back into the same boat as the DataView with having to copy rows to a new DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

It may be quicker to sort in database with all the indexes and stats available, especially if you paginate the result before displaying to the user.

Comment: I agree, but moving it to the database isn't an option at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sheng here, when you have to sorting 50 - 100k rows it's time to move some logic to the layer that is meant just for that, the database. Create a stored Procedure that takes the rowlimit and current page as parameters, or jsut build your select statement based on those values, .NET is fast, but not optimized for these kind of operations, where as SQL server (or any RDBMS for that matter).

Comment: While agree with you 100%, that's not an option. The application architecture and timeline does not accommodate moving the sort to the database.

Comment: Then maybe move the datastoreage sorting to a lower level in the form of some generic list holding your data as strongly types objects in stead of rows in a datatable / view, then do a sort on that (using LINQ maybe) and then just rebind the grid (or however you are representing the data).